# How to generate dynamically combinations of list in python

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic, nested-loops

I want to generate combination dynamically in python, I have a var `sessionperweeks` (between 2 and 6)

```
if sessionperweeks==2

    for i in range(0,7):
        for j in range(i+1,7):
            combins.append([i,j])

if sessionperweeks==3

    for i in range(0,7):
        for j in range(i+1,7):
            for k in range(j+1,7):
                combins.append([i,j,k])
```

and so on

Comment: look into itertools.

Comment: post sample input and expected output

Comment: What I want is all the combinations of all days of a week. (between 0 and 6) of a size of ``sessionperweeks`` (e.g. if sessionperweeks==2 [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5],[0,6],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[4,5],[4,6],[5,6]])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, using `combinations` from `itertools` to pick sessions per week from 0-6:

```
from itertools import combinations

sessionsperweek = int(input("Enter sessions per week:"))

combins = list(combinations(range(7), sessionsperweek))
print("Your possible combinations are:")
print(combins)
```

Example run with 2 (since OP updated):

```
Enter sessions per week:2
Your possible combinations are:
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]
```

Example run:

```
Enter sessions per week:6
Your possible combinations are:
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
```